# How to measure frequency of AC Voltage(In range of 0.05-5v) using micro-controller?

Tags: ac, dc, frequency, frequency-measurement

I have one sensor which outputs in the range of 0-5v AC voltage and I want to measure a frequency of this signal using the microcontroller ?

Is there any IC which gives digital pulse in output when input of 0.05-5v AC voltage is given? and using that pulse i can measure the frequency using micro-controller?

Frequency range will be within 0.5 Hz to 1500 Hz and Voltage range:- 0.05 - 5v
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an analog input pin on the MCU? The "IC" you are looking for is a simple comparator.

Comment: Then just read the analog voltage, do some filtering and calculate the frequency..

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do but it will not be an accurate result.I guess. but as you suggest comparator should work. but i need to decide the source of reference voltage

Comment: What range of frequency? No uC ADC is going to keep up if the signal frequency is 100 MHz.

Comment: Frequency range will be within 0.5 Hz to 1500 Hz

Comment: (1) You can't detect a frequency on a 0 V signal. What is your minimum voltage specification? (2) Why do you think that Eugene's method won't work? All the info into your question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Voltage range will be within 0.05v to 5v.
Eugene's method will not work as i required to measure the frequency, not a voltage. I can't filter anything from ADC of uC.

Comment: Eugene is recommending that you filter in software to catch any noise. e.g., If the voltage goes above 0.03 V then ignore any low for 1/1500 s (probably 1/2000 s in practice). Does your MCU have a comparator input?

Comment: No ,My MCU do not have the comparator input. However using Eugene's method i can measure it.
Any other suggestion will be appreciated. any suitable comparator IC ?

Comment: What micro are you using? I'd be surprised itf there was no comparator on it.

Comment: Why a HW comparator is needed? You have an ADC and you have a `==`, `>`, `<` C operators.

Comment: "ADC pin is present on MCU." - what is its resolution (number of bits) and input voltage range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming rate of change in amplitude(Vrms or Vpk-Vpk) is very slow compared to the frequencies:

1. Start a counter which can count the lowest frequency without overflow but with clock frequency larger a bit larger than the highest frequnecy.
2. Sample the data using ADC (higher the better but >3000Hz).Adding a low pass filter would be good idea.
3. When you find the max data point, time-stamp the counter.
4. Wait to get the min data point, time-stamp. Take the difference, calculate the frequency.
5. DONE.

If change of amplitude is also there, then you need to use PLL.